# SignalR returning 404 on /negotiate

Tags: signalr

I'm using signalR - the following URL usually works:

> signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&username=bla&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22apphub%22%7D%5D&_=1427859215639

But when the cookie expires and the user becomes unauthenticated, I start getting 404s on this request.  Is there any way to allow requests to /signalr to not require authentication?

My clientside code:

```
   if (app.isAuthenticated()) {
            //Start the connection.
            window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start();
   }
```

Comment: Cookies not recomended to use for `signalr` authentication

Comment: Is the hub on the server-side starting correctly? Try to open the client hub by entering the url in your browser: `http://yourdomain/signalr/hubs` if you see some javascript then your hub started successfully, if not, the problem is that your hub isn't ready and the auto-generated script is not there